# Python function returns pair of values

Tags: python, function

I have seen the following python code:

```
W_grads, _ = backward_gradient(X, S, grad_out, wRec)
```

And in the function backward_gradient, I have the following return statement:

```
return (wx_grad, wRec_grad), grad_over_time
```

What exactly does the underscore represent? Also, I think we are storing the return value of the pair of (wx_grad,wRec_grad) in W_grads. Is this correct?

Comment: Underscore just represents a short variable name, usually a trash placeholder with a value you won't normally use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function returns two values:

1. A tuple containing two values: `(wx_grad, wRec_grad)`
2. Then the single value `grad_over_time`

This code:

```
W_grads, _ = backward_gradient(X, S, grad_out, wRec)
```

Assigns the tuple to `W_grads` and assigns `grad_over_time` to a variable named `_`.

The variable name `_` is used as a placeholder for when you don't really care about the variable, you have to assign it to something but you don't want to use it. In this example the code calling the function doesn't care about the value `grad_over_time` so it assigns it to the variable `_`

Answer (score 1):

`_` is just a variable. `backward_gradient` will return a tuple like this `((x,y),z)`, so the value of `z` or `grad_over_time` will go into the `_`.

Yes, you're storing `(wx_grad,wRec_grad)` in `W_grads`.

Answer (score 0):

visit http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_if__name__equals__main__.php
this may helps you to understand _ and __ in python